Why is screen using lots of memory over time?
From time to time I find that a Digitalocean server gets slower, had low memory...
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           985M        678M         63M         60M        244M         83M
Swap:          5.0G        455M        4.6G

I have a script that re-starts an ongoing process using a simple script calling itself as described here: https://howtotrainyourrobot.com/keeping-a-process-running-with-a-3-line-bash-script/
After some time it may re-start itself, and echo out a bunch of output... but if I re start the process with a "killall screen" then starting "screen" and running the ongoing shell script again, I see memory drastically reduces:
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           985M        610M        125M         67M        249M        144M
Swap:          5.0G        390M        4.6G


And server seems to be responding faster. Especially if this re-start of screen hasn't been done in many weeks. Is this caused by some memory leak of Screen or perhaps the ongoing output of the ongoing process echoing to "screen"?

At least in my case it was a scrollback buffer. All in all, screen is not very good solution for long-running services; consider using systemd for that.

Your application does this?

Call program
Sleep
Invoke self
?

Over time you will end up with quite a large stack, if script A calls itself, you have say PID10 running calling PID11 which calls PID12. You must have thousands of copies of your script running in memory at some point, parents with thousands of children. Killing screen (parent of all), kills all child processes and resolves the issue.
This is a very very bad approach. You can solve it simply by using a loop instead:
while true; do
your-commands-here
done

That’s it. The script will execute your commands indefinitely in a loop. Call that in your screen and you are sorted. The suggestion of using systemd for this will not help if your script is built this way.
Example run ps and grep every 10 seconds:
while true; do
ps |grep bob
sleep 10
done

You can keep it in a screen session then. Once you do this, THEN you can improve even more by writing a systemd service file to use instead of screen. Or if you need to do something only every minute (or less) investigate using cron to call your script (no loop required, cron can call your script every minute or less frequently).
But basically the issue is the script you write. It should never indefinitely call itself as the previous copy will not exit until the next one exits (which won’t exit as it will just call another copy). It’s a slow fork bomb.
